# Fragment v4 animation crashes

Tags: android

I'm using Fragment v4 with min API = 14.

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();        
    ft.setCustomAnimations(
             R.anim.fragment_slide_left_enter,
             R.anim.fragment_slide_left_exit,
             R.anim.fragment_slide_right_enter,
             R.anim.fragment_slide_right_exit);
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, myLogFragment).commit();
```

but when I use the animation the app crashes

```
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899): Process: com.ingenico.rbasimulator, PID: 5899
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ingenico.rbasimulator/com.ingenico.rbasimulator.EcrActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:126)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:116)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:93)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:74)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimation(FragmentManager.java:786)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:963)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
04-23 16:36:01.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5899):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
```

how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to convert your `R.anim` files to `R.animation`

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#declaring-xml

> To distinguish animation files that use the new property animation APIs from those that use the legacy view animation framework, starting with Android 3.1, you should save the XML files for property animations in the res/animator/ directory (instead of res/anim/). Using the animator directory name is optional, but necessary if you want to use the layout editor tools in the Eclipse ADT plugin (ADT 11.0.0+), because ADT only searches the res/animator/ directory for property animation resources.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply `objectAnimator` on `FragmentTransaction` from `support library`. But support library can apply only `ValueProperty` animations like `Alpha`, `Translation`... `AnimatorSet`

```
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:toXDelta="0%p"/>
```

try this